# How to create a box with rounded corners at the top, but normal corners at the bottom?

Tags: html, css, rounded-corners

I'm having the following code:

```
<div class="box"> 
 <div class="title">
  <a>Title</a>
 </div>
 <div class="content">
  <a>Content</a>
 </div>
</div>
```

I'd like to style it with CSS and become the following result:

[image: Box with rounded corners]

However, I don't know how to style the 'title' part as I want it. The top corners should be rounded, but the ones at the bottom shouldn't. Vice versa for the 'content' part.

How can I do that?

Comment: Go go gadget google I would say

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify each corner's radius individually via:

```
border-top-left-radius: 24px;
border-top-right-radius: 24px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
```

Or combine that into one...

```
border-radius:24px 24px 0 0;
```

(values are clockwise from top-left)

There's a generator here - http://border-radius.com/ - but it should be easy enough to work out without.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this website to generate css for rounded corners.

http://border-radius.com

Basically you just need to specify which corner you want to set the bodrer radius for, e.g.: 
     border-top-left-radius: 5px